# Fortran: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, gfortran, macos-high-sierra

I am using the gfortran compiler on mac osx mavericks. I have installed Xcode and command line tools. I am trying to compile a simple helloworld program with gfortran to test whether everything works, but unfortunately it doesn't work. The error message seems to suggest that I have no main function, but I don't see the error in the code:

```
      program hello
         print *, "Hello World!"
      end program hello
```

But when i try to compile using

```
gfortran helloworld.f
```

I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "start", referenced from:
     -u command line option
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I do not understand what is wrong and I am on the verge of despair. I tried with gfortran 4.8.2 as well as gfortran 4.9.0, I tried reinstalling Xcode and Command Line Tools but nothing seems to work.

I am aware similar questions have been asked, but I was not able to find a solution to my problem. I would be happy even with a sloppy workaround, as long as I can get the compiler to run...

Comment: How did you install `gfortran`?

Comment: I tried different methods. I tried the autoinstallers from https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries (both version 4.8.2 and 4.9.0) as well as manually installing with .tar files. I always get the same error. I honestly think the problem is that gfortran can't find some files or uses the wrong files, as everything works fine on Ubuntu (tried with VirtualBox).

Answer (score 2):

Oh my dear. Found the solution about a minute after staring the bounty. Rather than using the recommended installer from https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries I just installed it with

```
brew install gcc
```

The gfortran now compiled without complaining.

Comment: The brew command doesn't work on Big Sur as it cannot write to the system folders such as /usr/bin etc.

Comment: @NateLockwood That did not strike me in 2018 ;-) Anyhow, thanks for the hint.

Comment: Actually I found that brew only needs access to the contents of  /usr/local and Apple allows that.

Comment: @NateLockwood So finally no issue at all?

Comment: Yes, no issue at all.  For this problem I found that 'man' is my best friend.